# Label() displays a label without label_1=Label()?

Tags: tkinter, widget, label

I have a little app I'm testing various widgets before implementing them in a main code file and I noticed that I had what looks like an erroneous way to display a label, but it still worked and caused no error.  Rather than what I would normally do which would be: `Label2=Label(frame1, text='second label').place(x=30,y=90)` I had `Label(frame1, text='frame1').place(x=30,y=50)` and both rendered correctly.  So I'm wondering why the second line worked and wouldn't it be unable to be referenced since there's no variable assigned to it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So I'm wondering why the second line worked

The second line worked simply because that's how it's designed to work. You don't need to keep a reference to a tkinter widget for it to work.

> ... and wouldn't it be unable to be referenced since there's no variable assigned to it?

Yes, that is the drawback to not saving a reference - you have no easy way to reference the widget after it has been created. You can still get a reference through various means, but it's simpler just to always keep a reference.

Plus, my opinion is that it's best to separate widget creation from widget layout. I find tkinter apps much easier to read when all layout widgets for a set of siblings are in a single block, rather than interlaced with code that creates the widgets.

Comment: Not only readability, but I just discovered that using ```.place()``` on the variable assignment line caused me trouble in placing a label on a frame that is on a tab.  (Then I also placed the tabs in another frame and this flexibility is very cool)